# Extracting Firmware problem with Binwalk

Tags: firmware, embedded

I'm in the process of trying to reverse engineer a firmware from unknown vendor. Here's what I got so far

I have the firmware image (.mg file). AFAIK it's no common image, I couldn't find any information about it from googling
Here's the binwalk output:

```
DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2149          0x865           HTML document header
2685          0xA7D           HTML document footer
2685          0xA7D           HTML document header
3052          0xBEC           HTML document footer
3052          0xBEC           HTML document header
3483          0xD9B           HTML document footer
3483          0xD9B           HTML document header
3747          0xEA3           HTML document footer
3747          0xEA3           HTML document header
5542          0x15A6          HTML document footer
8071          0x1F87          HTML document header
10462         0x28DE          HTML document footer
10463         0x28DF          HTML document header
10962         0x2AD2          HTML document footer
43377         0xA971          HTML document header
43752         0xAAE8          HTML document footer
43753         0xAAE9          HTML document header
47269         0xB8A5          HTML document footer
47269         0xB8A5          HTML document header
50689         0xC601          HTML document footer
50690         0xC602          HTML document header
52285         0xCC3D          HTML document footer
52289         0xCC41          HTML document header
54387         0xD473          HTML document footer
54389         0xD475          HTML document header
66620         0x1043C         HTML document footer
66621         0x1043D         HTML document header
70158         0x1120E         HTML document footer
70159         0x1120F         HTML document header
89096         0x15C08         HTML document footer
89329         0x15CF1         Copyright string: " © 2008.  All rights reserved."
96973         0x17ACD         GIF image data, version "89a", 9 x 9
97819         0x17E1B         GIF image data, version "89a", 1600 x 3
98790         0x181E6         GIF image data, version "89a", 780 x 10
99797         0x185D5         GIF image data, version "89a", 780 x 10
100806        0x189C6         HTML document header
126955        0x1EFEB         HTML document footer
126957        0x1EFED         HTML document header
133790        0x20A9E         HTML document footer
133792        0x20AA0         HTML document header
149863        0x24967         HTML document footer
149865        0x24969         HTML document header
157824        0x26880         HTML document footer
157826        0x26882         HTML document header
173039        0x2A3EF         HTML document footer
173041        0x2A3F1         HTML document header
201137        0x311B1         HTML document footer
201139        0x311B3         HTML document header
207772        0x32B9C         HTML document footer
207773        0x32B9D         HTML document header
219240        0x35868         HTML document footer
219241        0x35869         HTML document header
220859        0x35EBB         HTML document footer
220860        0x35EBC         HTML document header
229141        0x37F15         HTML document footer
229142        0x37F16         HTML document header
237943        0x3A177         HTML document footer
237943        0x3A177         HTML document header
243109        0x3B5A5         HTML document footer
243110        0x3B5A6         HTML document header
248986        0x3CC9A         HTML document footer
248987        0x3CC9B         HTML document header
256674        0x3EAA2         HTML document footer
256675        0x3EAA3         HTML document header
264418        0x408E2         HTML document footer
264419        0x408E3         HTML document header
267737        0x415D9         HTML document footer
267791        0x4160F         HTML document header
278611        0x44053         HTML document footer
278612        0x44054         HTML document header
302510        0x49DAE         HTML document footer
302511        0x49DAF         HTML document header
340467        0x531F3         HTML document footer
340468        0x531F4         HTML document header
350590        0x5597E         HTML document footer
350591        0x5597F         HTML document header
353983        0x566BF         HTML document footer
353984        0x566C0         HTML document header
400086        0x61AD6         HTML document footer
400087        0x61AD7         HTML document header
402883        0x625C3         HTML document footer
936805        0xE4B65         Zlib compressed data, default compression
949237        0xE7BF5         Zlib compressed data, compressed
959131        0xEA29B         Zlib compressed data, compressed
992718        0xF25CE         Zlib compressed data, best compression
999966        0xF421E         Zlib compressed data, default compression
1014782       0xF7BFE         Zlib compressed data, default compression
1018489       0xF8A79         Zlib compressed data, default compression
1032857       0xFC299         Zlib compressed data, default compression
1042869       0xFE9B5         Zlib compressed data, compressed
1044292       0xFEF44         Zlib compressed data, best compression
1052372       0x100ED4        Zlib compressed data, compressed
1055182       0x1019CE        Zlib compressed data, default compression
1071400       0x105928        Zlib compressed data, default compression
1076050       0x106B52        Zlib compressed data, best compression
1096297       0x10BA69        Zlib compressed data, compressed
1137920       0x115D00        Zlib compressed data, compressed
1170902       0x11DDD6        Zlib compressed data, compressed
1186555       0x121AFB        Zlib compressed data, compressed
1188821       0x1223D5        Zlib compressed data, default compression
1195821       0x123F2D        Zlib compressed data, default compression
1201862       0x1256C6        Zlib compressed data, compressed
1236300       0x12DD4C        Zlib compressed data, compressed
1279273       0x138529        Zlib compressed data, compressed
1280971       0x138BCB        Zlib compressed data, compressed
1302926       0x13E18E        Zlib compressed data, best compression
1303266       0x13E2E2        Zlib compressed data, compressed
1312923       0x14089B        Zlib compressed data, default compression
1332979       0x1456F3        Zlib compressed data, default compression
1340608       0x1474C0        Zlib compressed data, best compression
1378862       0x150A2E        Zlib compressed data, compressed
1398072       0x155538        Zlib compressed data, default compression
1415562       0x15998A        Zlib compressed data, compressed
1464907       0x165A4B        Zlib compressed data, default compression
1500357       0x16E4C5        Zlib compressed data, best compression
1500644       0x16E5E4        Zlib compressed data, default compression
1527997       0x1750BD        compress'd data, 16 bits
1544522       0x17914A        Zlib compressed data, best compression
1552354       0x17AFE2        Zlib compressed data, best compression
1571408       0x17FA50        Zlib compressed data, compressed
1581827       0x182303        Zlib compressed data, best compression
1591785       0x1849E9        Zlib compressed data, compressed
1605018       0x187D9A        Zlib compressed data, default compression
1620883       0x18BB93        Zlib compressed data, compressed
1657385       0x194A29        Zlib compressed data, compressed
1660472       0x195638        Zlib compressed data, compressed
1676765       0x1995DD        Zlib compressed data, default compression
1677967       0x199A8F        Zlib compressed data, best compression
1716067       0x1A2F63        Zlib compressed data, best compression
1805822       0x1B8DFE        Zlib compressed data, compressed
1816311       0x1BB6F7        Zlib compressed data, compressed
1828850       0x1BE7F2        Zlib compressed data, compressed
1847543       0x1C30F7        Zlib compressed data, compressed
1884695       0x1CC217        Zlib compressed data, compressed
1897488       0x1CF410        Zlib compressed data, best compression
1897690       0x1CF4DA        Zlib compressed data, compressed
1942524       0x1DA3FC        Zlib compressed data, best compression
1963605       0x1DF655        Zlib compressed data, compressed
1975034       0x1E22FA        Zlib compressed data, compressed
1977041       0x1E2AD1        Zlib compressed data, compressed
1997374       0x1E7A3E        Zlib compressed data, compressed
2036964       0x1F14E4        Zlib compressed data, default compression
2037783       0x1F1817        Zlib compressed data, compressed
2041756       0x1F279C        Zlib compressed data, compressed
2051259       0x1F4CBB        Zlib compressed data, compressed
2063154       0x1F7B32        Zlib compressed data, best compression
2072756       0x1FA0B4        Zlib compressed data, default compression
2076724       0x1FB034        Zlib compressed data, compressed
2082453       0x1FC695        Zlib compressed data, default compression
2093131       0x1FF04B        Zlib compressed data, compressed
2107066       0x2026BA        Zlib compressed data, compressed
2107321       0x2027B9        Zlib compressed data, default compression
2121073       0x205D71        Zlib compressed data, compressed
2125853       0x20701D        Zlib compressed data, best compression
2126493       0x20729D        Zlib compressed data, best compression
2154155       0x20DEAB        Zlib compressed data, compressed
2177138       0x213872        Zlib compressed data, compressed
2195782       0x218146        Zlib compressed data, best compression
2199697       0x219091        Zlib compressed data, compressed
2211810       0x21BFE2        Zlib compressed data, default compression
2237221       0x222325        Zlib compressed data, default compression
2245919       0x22451F        Zlib compressed data, best compression
2257118       0x2270DE        Zlib compressed data, compressed
2265100       0x22900C        Zlib compressed data, compressed
2276225       0x22BB81        Zlib compressed data, compressed
2285428       0x22DF74        Zlib compressed data, best compression
2286328       0x22E2F8        Zlib compressed data, best compression
2300068       0x2318A4        Zlib compressed data, compressed
2306513       0x2331D1        Zlib compressed data, default compression
2324445       0x2377DD        Zlib compressed data, default compression
2339864       0x23B418        Zlib compressed data, best compression
2349252       0x23D8C4        Zlib compressed data, compressed
2358483       0x23FCD3        Zlib compressed data, compressed
2375872       0x2440C0        Zlib compressed data, compressed
2383190       0x245D56        Zlib compressed data, default compression
2474107       0x25C07B        Zlib compressed data, default compression
2505436       0x263ADC        Zlib compressed data, compressed
2505514       0x263B2A        Zlib compressed data, compressed
2507416       0x264298        Zlib compressed data, best compression
2515542       0x266256        Zlib compressed data, compressed
2517896       0x266B88        Zlib compressed data, best compression
2520742       0x2676A6        Zlib compressed data, compressed
2526861       0x268E8D        Zlib compressed data, best compression
2534916       0x26AE04        Zlib compressed data, default compression
2561503       0x2715DF        Zlib compressed data, default compression
2569730       0x273602        Zlib compressed data, compressed
2583767       0x276CD7        Zlib compressed data, default compression
2602237       0x27B4FD        Zlib compressed data, default compression
2611477       0x27D915        Zlib compressed data, default compression
2626957       0x28158D        Zlib compressed data, compressed
2639089       0x2844F1        Zlib compressed data, compressed
2647278       0x2864EE        Zlib compressed data, default compression
2652206       0x28782E        Zlib compressed data, best compression
2664654       0x28A8CE        Zlib compressed data, best compression
2721674       0x29878A        Zlib compressed data, best compression
2722212       0x2989A4        Zlib compressed data, compressed
2729622       0x29A696        Zlib compressed data, default compression
2746239       0x29E77F        Zlib compressed data, compressed
2747460       0x29EC44        Zlib compressed data, best compression
2773475       0x2A51E3        Zlib compressed data, compressed
2912430       0x2C70AE        Zlib compressed data, compressed
2915559       0x2C7CE7        Zlib compressed data, best compression
2919137       0x2C8AE1        Zlib compressed data, compressed
2919398       0x2C8BE6        Zlib compressed data, default compression
2925208       0x2CA298        Zlib compressed data, default compression
2970697       0x2D5449        Zlib compressed data, compressed
2975629       0x2D678D        Zlib compressed data, compressed
3007894       0x2DE596        Zlib compressed data, compressed
3085804       0x2F15EC        Zlib compressed data, compressed
3092200       0x2F2EE8        Zlib compressed data, compressed
3109095       0x2F70E7        Zlib compressed data, default compression
3137073       0x2FDE31        Zlib compressed data, default compression
3159460       0x3035A4        Zlib compressed data, best compression
3169969       0x305EB1        Zlib compressed data, compressed
3174676       0x307114        Zlib compressed data, best compression
3190315       0x30AE2B        Zlib compressed data, default compression
3190481       0x30AED1        Zlib compressed data, compressed
3199853       0x30D36D        Zlib compressed data, best compression
3209970       0x30FAF2        Zlib compressed data, default compression
3233371       0x31565B        Zlib compressed data, compressed
3262017       0x31C641        Zlib compressed data, compressed
3294698       0x3245EA        Zlib compressed data, compressed
3294814       0x32465E        Zlib compressed data, best compression
3300772       0x325DA4        Zlib compressed data, compressed
3314325       0x329295        Zlib compressed data, default compression
3325430       0x32BDF6        Zlib compressed data, best compression
3347539       0x331453        Zlib compressed data, default compression
3381973       0x339AD5        Zlib compressed data, compressed
3384096       0x33A320        Zlib compressed data, compressed
3426731       0x3449AB        Zlib compressed data, best compression
3436707       0x3470A3        Zlib compressed data, best compression
3439327       0x347ADF        Zlib compressed data, best compression
3483067       0x3525BB        Zlib compressed data, default compression
3488551       0x353B27        Zlib compressed data, default compression
3493009       0x354C91        Zlib compressed data, default compression
3494362       0x3551DA        Zlib compressed data, default compression
3499219       0x3564D3        Zlib compressed data, best compression
3538245       0x35FD45        Zlib compressed data, compressed
3579428       0x369E24        Zlib compressed data, compressed
3588400       0x36C130        Zlib compressed data, compressed
3597734       0x36E5A6        Zlib compressed data, default compression
3609086       0x3711FE        Zlib compressed data, compressed
3617545       0x373309        Zlib compressed data, default compression
3622662       0x374706        Zlib compressed data, compressed
3626922       0x3757AA        Zlib compressed data, best compression
3634992       0x377730        Zlib compressed data, best compression
3638148       0x378384        Zlib compressed data, default compression
3638417       0x378491        Zlib compressed data, best compression
3688902       0x3849C6        Zlib compressed data, compressed
3698631       0x386FC7        Zlib compressed data, best compression
3713175       0x38A897        Zlib compressed data, best compression
3781687       0x39B437        Zlib compressed data, default compression
3786285       0x39C62D        Zlib compressed data, default compression
3794941       0x39E7FD        Zlib compressed data, default compression
3816840       0x3A3D88        Zlib compressed data, best compression
3817656       0x3A40B8        Zlib compressed data, default compression
3829859       0x3A7063        Zlib compressed data, compressed
3859678       0x3AE4DE        Zlib compressed data, best compression
3887499       0x3B518B        Zlib compressed data, best compression
3902283       0x3B8B4B        Zlib compressed data, default compression
3923673       0x3BDED9        Zlib compressed data, best compression
3927277       0x3BECED        Zlib compressed data, best compression
3974662       0x3CA606        Zlib compressed data, compressed
3995965       0x3CF93D        Zlib compressed data, default compression
4004880       0x3D1C10        Zlib compressed data, compressed
4024426       0x3D686A        Zlib compressed data, default compression
4076111       0x3E324F        Zlib compressed data, compressed
4097672       0x3E8688        Zlib compressed data, best compression
4115526       0x3ECC46        Zlib compressed data, best compression
4115649       0x3ECCC1        Zlib compressed data, best compression
4122032       0x3EE5B0        Zlib compressed data, best compression
4124189       0x3EEE1D        Zlib compressed data, best compression
4129024       0x3F0100        Zlib compressed data, compressed
4181033       0x3FCC29        Zlib compressed data, default compression
4218129       0x405D11        Zlib compressed data, compressed
4219339       0x4061CB        Zlib compressed data, best compression
4221408       0x4069E0        Zlib compressed data, best compression
4239114       0x40AF0A        Zlib compressed data, compressed
4245809       0x40C931        Zlib compressed data, best compression
4277644       0x41458C        Zlib compressed data, compressed
4289972       0x4175B4        Zlib compressed data, compressed
4300292       0x419E04        Zlib compressed data, best compression
4319935       0x41EABF        Zlib compressed data, compressed
4319988       0x41EAF4        Zlib compressed data, compressed
4320041       0x41EB29        Zlib compressed data, compressed
4320089       0x41EB59        Zlib compressed data, compressed
4350321       0x426171        Zlib compressed data, compressed
4375063       0x42C217        Zlib compressed data, compressed
4414926       0x435DCE        Zlib compressed data, compressed
4417582       0x43682E        Zlib compressed data, compressed
4430754       0x439BA2        Zlib compressed data, best compression
4430955       0x439C6B        Zlib compressed data, best compression
4433422       0x43A60E        Zlib compressed data, compressed
4440964       0x43C384        Zlib compressed data, default compression
4459836       0x440D3C        Zlib compressed data, best compression
4465037       0x44218D        Zlib compressed data, compressed
4491474       0x4488D2        Zlib compressed data, compressed
4525321       0x450D09        Zlib compressed data, compressed
4536020       0x4536D4        Zlib compressed data, default compression
4539019       0x45428B        Zlib compressed data, best compression
4547686       0x456466        Zlib compressed data, compressed
4594046       0x46197E        Zlib compressed data, compressed
4595742       0x46201E        Zlib compressed data, compressed
4611527       0x465DC7        Zlib compressed data, compressed
4621480       0x4684A8        Zlib compressed data, best compression
4622546       0x4688D2        Zlib compressed data, best compression
4658238       0x47143E        Zlib compressed data, compressed
4666730       0x47356A        Zlib compressed data, best compression
4682920       0x4774A8        Zlib compressed data, best compression
4687391       0x47861F        Zlib compressed data, compressed
4725536       0x481B20        Zlib compressed data, compressed
4729111       0x482917        Zlib compressed data, default compression
4739376       0x485130        Zlib compressed data, best compression
4747013       0x486F05        Zlib compressed data, compressed
4764107       0x48B1CB        Zlib compressed data, compressed
4774983       0x48DC47        Zlib compressed data, default compression
4775153       0x48DCF1        Zlib compressed data, best compression
4828104       0x49ABC8        Zlib compressed data, best compression
4866122       0x4A404A        Zlib compressed data, compressed
4895722       0x4AB3EA        Zlib compressed data, compressed
4934732       0x4B4C4C        Zlib compressed data, default compression
4940722       0x4B63B2        Zlib compressed data, default compression
4949644       0x4B868C        Zlib compressed data, compressed
4983247       0x4C09CF        Zlib compressed data, compressed
4992046       0x4C2C2E        Zlib compressed data, best compression
5023817       0x4CA849        Zlib compressed data, compressed
5037667       0x4CDE63        Zlib compressed data, compressed
5046276       0x4D0004        Zlib compressed data, best compression
5048862       0x4D0A1E        Zlib compressed data, compressed
5050674       0x4D1132        Zlib compressed data, compressed
5073060       0x4D68A4        Zlib compressed data, default compression
5092725       0x4DB575        Zlib compressed data, default compression
5122481       0x4E29B1        Zlib compressed data, compressed
5122600       0x4E2A28        Zlib compressed data, compressed
5140098       0x4E6E82        Zlib compressed data, compressed
5140130       0x4E6EA2        Zlib compressed data, compressed
```

It all seems like a false positive because when I run  binwalk -e I get these files as output:

```
100ED4.zlib 15998A.zlib 1CF410.zlib 20AA0.html  263ADC.zlib 29E77F.zlib 311B3.html  369E24.zlib 3B5A6.html  40C931.zlib 45428B.zlib 4B63B2.zlib B8A5.html
1019CE.zlib 165A4B.zlib 1CF4DA.zlib 20DEAB.zlib 263B2A.zlib 29EC44.zlib 31565B.zlib 36C130.zlib 3B8B4B.zlib 41458C.zlib 456466.zlib 4B868C.zlib BEC.html
1043D.html  16E4C5.zlib 1DA3FC.zlib 213872.zlib 264298.zlib 2A3F1.html  31C641.zlib 36E5A6.zlib 3BDED9.zlib 4160F.html  46197E.zlib 4C09CF.zlib C602.html
105928.zlib 16E5E4.zlib 1DF655.zlib 218146.zlib 266256.zlib 2A51E3.zlib 3245EA.zlib 3711FE.zlib 3BECED.zlib 4175B4.zlib 46201E.zlib 4C2C2E.zlib CC41.html
106B52.zlib 1750BD.Z    1E22FA.zlib 219091.zlib 266B88.zlib 2C70AE.zlib 32465E.zlib 373309.zlib 3CA606.zlib 419E04.zlib 465DC7.zlib 4CA849.zlib D475.html
10BA69.zlib 17914A.zlib 1E2AD1.zlib 21BFE2.zlib 2676A6.zlib 2C7CE7.zlib 325DA4.zlib 374706.zlib 3CC9B.html  41EABF.zlib 4684A8.zlib 4CDE63.zlib D9B.html
1120F.html  17AFE2.zlib 1E7A3E.zlib 222325.zlib 26882.html  2C8AE1.zlib 329295.zlib 3757AA.zlib 3CF93D.zlib 41EAF4.zlib 4688D2.zlib 4D0004.zlib E4B65.zlib
115D00.zlib 17FA50.zlib 1EFED.html  22451F.zlib 268E8D.zlib 2C8BE6.zlib 32B9D.html  377730.zlib 3D1C10.zlib 41EB29.zlib 47143E.zlib 4D0A1E.zlib E7BF5.zlib
11DDD6.zlib 182303.zlib 1F14E4.zlib 2270DE.zlib 26AE04.zlib 2CA298.zlib 32BDF6.zlib 378384.zlib 3D686A.zlib 41EB59.zlib 47356A.zlib 4D1132.zlib EA29B.zlib
121AFB.zlib 1849E9.zlib 1F1817.zlib 22900C.zlib 2715DF.zlib 2D5449.zlib 331453.zlib 378491.zlib 3E324F.zlib 426171.zlib 4774A8.zlib 4D68A4.zlib EA3.html
1223D5.zlib 187D9A.zlib 1F279C.zlib 22BB81.zlib 273602.zlib 2D678D.zlib 339AD5.zlib 37F16.html  3E8688.zlib 42C217.zlib 47861F.zlib 4DB575.zlib F25CE.zlib
123F2D.zlib 189C6.html  1F4CBB.zlib 22DF74.zlib 276CD7.zlib 2DE596.zlib 33A320.zlib 3849C6.zlib 3EAA3.html  435DCE.zlib 481B20.zlib 4E29B1.zlib F421E.zlib
1256C6.zlib 18BB93.zlib 1F7B32.zlib 22E2F8.zlib 27B4FD.zlib 2F15EC.zlib 3449AB.zlib 386FC7.zlib 3ECC46.zlib 43682E.zlib 482917.zlib 4E2A28.zlib F7BFE.zlib
12DD4C.zlib 194A29.zlib 1F87.html   2318A4.zlib 27D915.zlib 2F2EE8.zlib 3470A3.zlib 38A897.zlib 3ECCC1.zlib 439BA2.zlib 485130.zlib 4E6E82.zlib F8A79.zlib
138529.zlib 195638.zlib 1FA0B4.zlib 2331D1.zlib 28158D.zlib 2F70E7.zlib 347ADF.zlib 39B437.zlib 3EE5B0.zlib 439C6B.zlib 486F05.zlib 4E6EA2.zlib FC299.zlib
138BCB.zlib 1995DD.zlib 1FB034.zlib 2377DD.zlib 2844F1.zlib 2FDE31.zlib 3525BB.zlib 39C62D.zlib 3EEE1D.zlib 43A60E.zlib 48B1CB.zlib 531F4.html  FE9B5.zlib
13E18E.zlib 199A8F.zlib 1FC695.zlib 23B418.zlib 2864EE.zlib 3035A4.zlib 353B27.zlib 39E7FD.zlib 3F0100.zlib 43C384.zlib 48DC47.zlib 5597F.html  FEF44.zlib
13E2E2.zlib 1A2F63.zlib 1FF04B.zlib 23D8C4.zlib 28782E.zlib 305EB1.zlib 354C91.zlib 3A177.html  3FCC29.zlib 44054.html  48DCF1.zlib 566C0.html
14089B.zlib 1B8DFE.zlib 2026BA.zlib 23FCD3.zlib 28A8CE.zlib 307114.zlib 3551DA.zlib 3A3D88.zlib 405D11.zlib 440D3C.zlib 49ABC8.zlib 61AD7.html
1456F3.zlib 1BB6F7.zlib 2027B9.zlib 2440C0.zlib 28DF.html   30AE2B.zlib 3564D3.zlib 3A40B8.zlib 4061CB.zlib 44218D.zlib 49DAF.html  865.html
1474C0.zlib 1BE7F2.zlib 205D71.zlib 245D56.zlib 29878A.zlib 30AED1.zlib 35869.html  3A7063.zlib 4069E0.zlib 4488D2.zlib 4A404A.zlib A7D.html
150A2E.zlib 1C30F7.zlib 20701D.zlib 24969.html  2989A4.zlib 30D36D.zlib 35EBC.html  3AE4DE.zlib 408E3.html  450D09.zlib 4AB3EA.zlib A971.html
155538.zlib 1CC217.zlib 20729D.zlib 25C07B.zlib 29A696.zlib 30FAF2.zlib 35FD45.zlib 3B518B.zlib 40AF0A.zlib 4536D4.zlib 4B4C4C.zlib AAE9.html
```

The zlib files give me error during extraction. ( I can't unzip the zlib files)

From hexdump output and strings command I see quite a lot of ascii which I guess indicates it's not encrypted.

When I open the HTML files I see some binaries which apparently got combined with HTML files.

[image]

[image]

My question is: Where do I go from here?

Comment: Plenty of plain files. It's probably a proprietary (since binwalk doesn't recognize it) uncompressed archive or filesystem format. I would start digging into it with an hex editor and see if I can find some sort of index/table.

Comment: What @Andrea says. The HTML snippet appears self-contained - there must be an index of some kind. Locate all of the HTML starts and check the entire file for them. Mind that there may be a fixed offset added to each. If this really is a set of packed files, there could also be a length member (but not necessarily so), and possibly more metadata.

Comment: Nice tool, never heard of it before yesterday, definitely gotta pick it up

Comment: Can you share the file you are analyzing?